# Unable to rewrite the url with multiple condition

Tags: php, apache

i need following url to be changed as

http://example.com/Automobile/automotive_listing_subcategory?id=1&title=car-suv also need to rewrite urls such as: http://example.com/Automobile/automotive_listing_category?aid=1&title=car-suv

etc. these all pages under same folder. i had the following code.first one works.but if try to rewrite according to second condition it doesnt work. Anybody please help me.Am not an expert in this area. please correct me if there is any errors.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /Automobile/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\&title=    ([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&title=$3[QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?aid=([^&]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)?/?$ $1.php?aid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why you tag `Javascript` ,`html` ,`MySQL` ??

Answer (score 0):

you can read https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ and what you need are **regular expressions** (regexes)

regexes are are chapter for themselves and very tricky to understand sometimes 
they can also be used with linux commands like grep, sed,...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

the Apache server has a **(url) rewrite engine**: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Thanks ralf htp....can you please help me to find if there is any mistake in my code.....

Comment: too hard for me. maybe its the lowest line: RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)?/?$ $1.php?aid=$2 [L,QSA]    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)__/__([^/]+)__/?__$ $1.php?aid=$2 [QSA,L]